# File : "Upload a valid image" using Postman in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, imagefield, django-storage

I am using Django Rest Framework to upload profile picture and Google Cloud Storage to store my images. I test my API with Postman and i have this result :
[Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aijTg.png)
And here is my Postman headers : [Postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oYzj.png)

This is my code :

```
class ProfilePictureSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
file = serializers.ImageField()

class UploadProfilePictureAPI(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]

@staticmethod
def post(request):
    input_serializer = serializers.ProfilePictureSerializer(
        data=request.data
    )
    input_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    profile = ProfileService.upload_profile_picture(
        request.user,
        **input_serializer.validated_data
    )

    output_serializer = serializers.ProfileSerializer(profile)
    return Response(
        output_serializer.data,
        status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED
    )

@staticmethod
def upload_profile_picture(user, file):
    user.profile.profile_picture = file
    user.profile.save()
    return user.profile

path(
    'upload/picture',
    views.UploadProfilePictureAPI.as_view(),
    name='api_upload_profile_picture'
),
```

I does not understand why I have this response. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here might be that `FileUploadParser` expects you to just send raw binary data (you can see the `binary` option in Postman).

In your current example, can you just try to send the `binary` data like so?

[image]

For multipart form you should use the `MultiPartParser`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser

Comment: Thank you, i will try this today and tell you if it works !

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with binary file in Postman ! Finally I use multipart form with MultiPartParser because it works and it is easier to send request with axios. Thank you again !

Comment: Glad it helped!